# Ternary for sidebar in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Sidebar component that has a `sidebarOpen` prop, ie: `<SidebarWrapper sidebarOpen={this.props.sidebarOpen}>`

I also have a button where the `onClick` toggles the `sidebarOpen` to true & false.

I also have an event listener where when in mobile, set the `sideBarOpen` to false. This is the function:

```
setSidebar = () => {
 const isMobile = (typeof window !== 'undefined') && (window.innerWidth < 500)

 if(isMobile) {
   this.props.openSidebar(false)
 } else {
   this.props.openSidebar(true)
 }
}
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is, if you click on the button while in mobile and resize the screen, the sidebar should stay open without a flicker.

[Video Here](https://www.useloom.com/share/aeb517ccc91940d9b3a2a2119f4255bf)

Here is the full component:

```
import React from 'react'

import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { toggleDarkTheme, openSidebar } from '../../actions/layout'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import {SidebarWrapper} from './styles'


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    toggleDarkTheme: bindActionCreators(toggleDarkTheme, dispatch),
    openSidebar: bindActionCreators(openSidebar, dispatch)
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ sidebarOpen: state.layout.sidebarOpen });

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(class Sidebar extends React.Component {

  setSidebar = () => {
    const isMobile = (typeof window !== 'undefined') && (window.innerWidth < 500)

    if(isMobile) {
      this.props.openSidebar(false)
    } else {
      this.props.openSidebar(true)
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.setSidebar);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.setSidebar);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <SidebarWrapper sidebarOpen={this.props.sidebarOpen}>
          <button onClick={this.props.toggleDarkTheme}>Darkness</button>
      </SidebarWrapper>
    )
  }
})
```

& the styles:

```
import styled from 'styled-components'
import breakpoint from 'styled-components-breakpoint'

export const SidebarWrapper = styled.div`
  display: ${props => props.sidebarOpen ? 'flex' : 'none'};
  flex-direction: column;

`
```

Comment: You should use state here which would have the `opened` state and if there is no need to change it (if still mobile and sidebar already opened) - do nothing (this won't trigger rerender). Then there won't be any flickering.

Comment: @extempl I thought that as well, but didn't solve the issue. It has something to do with my if statement

Comment: Could you clarify what you trying to achieve here? from the description it looks like you want to have sidebar opened while resizing, but what for you need `isMobile` then? So, if we remove the `onResize` handler at all - you will have it opened until closed by hand. If this is not what you want - add more details, i.e. what is the expected result of when you open sidebar not on mobile and resizing - what then? What if you resizing from 1000px to 300 - how it should behave?